# What does it mean to extremise the action function?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, action

When studying RG, more specifically the scalar field theory in $D$ dimensions, I am told to consider the Lagrangian for a real scalar field:

$$\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 +\sum_{n>2} \frac{\lambda_n}{n}\phi^n.$$

Restricting ourselves to $\phi^4$ theory, we begin analysing the theory classically. The model is parameterised by two parameters, $m^2$ and $\lambda$. While $\lambda>0$ to make the theory well defined, no such restriction, no restriction is given to $m^2$, classically the action is extremised by:

$$m^2 \phi +\lambda \phi^3=0 \to \phi_0 =0, \phi_{\pm}=\frac{\sqrt{-m^2}}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

---

I don't understand what is meant by extremising the action.

And should the $\phi$ on the $m^2 \phi$ term on the LHS of this last equation be $m^2\phi^2$ instead?

Comment: Are you working in Euclidean signature? This may obfuscate physical solutions.

Comment: Also: You already seem to know what _extremising the action_ means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extremising the action just means finding the classical solution by the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), which eventually boils down to solving the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$ \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} =  \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}, $$
in this case
$$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi = V'(\phi) = m^2 \phi + \sum_{n > 2} \lambda_n \phi^{n-1} $$
with
$$ V(\phi) = \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 + \sum_{n > 2} \frac{\lambda_n}{n} \phi^{n-1}. $$
For the purpose of finding the vacuum expectation value (classical configuration with the lowest energy), which I suppose you are doing, note that both putting $\partial_\mu \phi = 0$ minimises the kinetic energy and putting the potential at its minimum value $V = V_\min$ (so $V'(\phi) = 0$) minimises potential energy. Furthermore, doing both at the same time is compatible with the Euler-Lagrange equation, so this must give the minimal energy solution. Then you get your equation.